# URLRewriter.net regex for querystrings

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting

I have this url:

> `http://www.site.com/products-book_1.aspx?promo=free`

Here is what I have in my web.config for the UrlRewriter rules:

> ```
> <rewrite url="~/products-(.+)_(\d+).aspx" to="~/product.aspx?pid=$2" />
> ```

What can I add to this expression to also retrieve the promo value?  The end result would be http://www.site.com/products.aspx?pid=1&promo=free

Or do I need to think about this a different way.  Every example I see just uses expression for the values before the extension, not after.  What about querystrings that need to be attached sometimes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<rewrite url="~/products-(.+)_(\d+).aspx?promo=(.*)" to="~/product.aspx?pid=$2&promo=$3" />
```

Actually this isn't really a good regex unless your URL will **only** contain the GET parameter 'promo' and none other.

**EDIT**

This might be slightly better: will only include promo parameter if it exists, else promo is left blank.

```
<rewrite url="~/products-(?:.+?)_(\d+).aspx(?:\?promo=(.*))*" to="~/product.aspx?pid=$1&promo=$2" />
```

Comment: thank you!!  I was able to get what I wanted, but I used:
<rewrite url="~/Product-(.+)_(\d+).aspx\?(.+)" to="~/product.aspx?pid=$2&amp;$3" />

This allows me to use other GET parameters as well.   But I'm going to look at your EDIT closely for some additional tips.

Comment: But of course, I hadn't thought of that. Yes that works quite well indeed. I'm not that great with regular expressions so I'm afraid I don't have any useful tips :)